# JavaScript works when FireFox console/inspector open, but not when closed

Tags: javascript

I have the following JavaScript
    
        
            
                
                
                
                    Close

```
@section('javascript')
@parent
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsrender/0.9.91/jsrender.min.js"></script>
<script>
function roundToTwo(num) {    
    return + (Math.round(num + "e+2")  + "e-2");
}
$(".pl-coord-link-button").on("click", function() {
    $("#pl-modal-map-content").html(
        $.templates("#pl-map-template").render({
            bbox1: roundToTwo($(this).data('lon') - 0.02),
            bbox2: roundToTwo($(this).data('lat') - 0.02),
            bbox3: roundToTwo($(this).data('lon') + 0.02),
            bbox4: roundToTwo($(this).data('lat') + 0.02),
            lat: $(this).data('lat'),
            lon: $(this).data('lon')
        })
    )
})
</script>
<script id="pl-map-template" type="text/x-jsrender">
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3 border">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" scrolling="no" src="http://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html?bbox=@{{:bbox1}}%2C@{{:bbox2}}%2C@{{:bbox3}}%2C@{{:bbox4}}&amp;marker=@{{:lat}}%2C@{{:lon}}&amp;layer=mapnik"></iframe>
</div>
<div class="py-2 text-muted pl-coordinates">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/?mlat=@{{:lat}}&amp;mlon=@{{:lon}}#map=5/@{{:lat}}/@{{:lon}}" class="pl-coord-link"><i class="fas fa-globe-americas" aria-hidden="true"></i>@{{:lat}}&deg; @{{:lon}}&deg;</a>
</div>
</script>
@endsection
```

When I open the console, the map zooms in as expected, but when I close it the map is all the way zoomed out

I don't understand how opening the console would change anything, I thought maybe it was because it made the window smaller, but I resized the window and it still doesn't work?

What changes when the console is open?

Update: Testing in Chrome Dev and everything works as expected, must be a FireFox specific bug

Comment: Opening console does indeed effectively change window size and map is likely configured to set zoom based on it's window dimensions within the iframe

Comment: If I resize the window though the problem persists

Comment: Put the rendered page elements in your question perhaps.  OR if it is a problem with the jsrender, tag as that and then create clear set of code that isolates THAT problem.

Comment: I do not see any `console.log` or other console calls in the code you posted. If the rendered code has that, please post that as that can and will break some browsers when the console is not open and is sometimes browser version specific.